# Каким способом можно добавить новое поле в базу данных и обновить её в приложении?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

есть база данных на SQL, уже подключенная к visual studio (WPF приложение), подключал через ADO. Теперь появилась нужда добавить новое поле и я не знаю как быть. Добавить поле в sql легко, но оно не обновляется же в visual studio, поэтому я в замешательстве, как это правильно сделать можно?

Comment: Покажите код, как вы работаете с базой данных. Без него мы вам вряд ли сможем чем-то помочь

Comment: я не до конца понимаю про какой код идёт речь, вы про model context cs ?